# Implement Python datetime delta with Flask and wtform

Tags: python, datetime, flask, flask-wtforms

With flask and wtforms I would like to control the `date_from` and `date_to` that the user enters.

```py
now = datetime.today()
two_month_ago = now - timedelta(days=60)
date_from = DateTimeField('date_from', format='%Y%m%d',validators=[DateRange(min=anchor_date, max=None, format='%Y%m%d')], default=two_month_ago)
date_to = DateTimeField('date_to', format='%Y%m%d',validators=[DateRange(min=anchor_date, max=None, format='%Y%m%d')], default=now)
```

This code is working fine but I found that the data is always returned same. After debugging the reason is now it's being stored. To solve this issue it's mentioned to use directly `datetime.today` instead of `datetime.today()`. But I am no longer able to use the delta to calculate two months ago. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the default to the callable.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def two_months_ago():
    return datetime.today() - timedelta(days=60)

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    date_from = DateTimeField(
        'date_from', 
        format='%Y%m%d',
        validators=[DateRange(min=anchor_date, max=None, format='%Y%m%d')],
        default=two_month_ago()
    )
    date_to = DateTimeField(
        'date_to', 
        format='%Y%m%d', 
        validators=[DateRange(min=anchor_date, max=None, format='%Y%m%d')], 
        default=datetime.today()
    )
```